# Unable to get text from disabled textbox

Tags: selenium

I need to print value of a disabled text box. The below given is the source code

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-2 form-group mb-2" xpath="1">
        <input name="SMDetailsViewModel.SoRSummaryRowID" class="form-control rum-disabled" id="SRowID" type="hidden" value="3908" tabindex="-1">
        <input name="SMDetailsViewModel.ID" **value**="20445" class="form-control rum-disabled " id="SID" type="text" tabindex="-1">
    </div>
```

The 'value' needs to get printed and it is dynamic value.
I have tried with CSS, Xpath like below

```
WebElement SoR=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#SID"));  With xpath as well 
        String SoRID=SoR.getText();
        System.out.println("Here SOR ID" +SoRID);
```

tried with GetAttribute as well

Answer (score 0):

Working with below

```
WebElement SoR=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#SID"));
        String SoRID=SoR.getAttribute("value");
        //String SoRID=SoR.getText();
        System.out.println("Here SOR ID" +SoRID);
```